# Angular js Dynamic Input and show value

Tags: angularjs

I want dynamic input in my form so that user can add many input as much he wants

Same time I want to display the value of it..

Example:
Suppose i have one input

```
Customer: <input type="text" ng-model="name"/> <!--first input>
<a>Add more</a>
```

I can easily get value for it

```
All customers <p ng-bind="name"></p>
```

BUT if users add one more customer name input, Then how can i show that value
Under "All customers

tag"

```
All customers <p ng-bind="name"></p>  // Customer1,Customer1 name here
```

Comment: sorry it's unclear to me, isolated scope????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array of objects on scope in conjunction with a `ng-repeat`. The button will then add to the array.

View:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in array">Name: <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" ></p>
<button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
<p>All customers</p>
<p ng-repeat="item in array">{{item.name}}</p>
```

Js:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.array = [];

  $scope.add = function () {
    $scope.array.push({ name: ''});
  }

  $scope.add();
});
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CeHLlQ0x44OomzbzklGz?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create array.

In your controller

```
$scope.inputs = [];

$scope.add = function() {
    $scope.inputs.push({value: ''});
}
$scope.add();
```

now in HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="input in inputs">
    <input type="text" ng-model="input.value" />
</div>
<button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
```

This is raw concept of how that might be done.

**Update**

Added plunker example
http://plnkr.co/edit/bHLXCjsP46GiixysZZ83?p=preview

Comment: Close. OP said it should start with one input so the array should start with one item

Comment: @sergey
How to remove [{"value":""}]
I want only plain..text

Comment: @DeadLock, unfortunately you cannot remove it. The element of array have to be an object. If it will be simple text line, it will not work. The only way around is a custom directive that will controll model view.